# On Facebook, how can I see future events someone is going to?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

When looking at a friend's page on Facebook, I sometimes see "Going to <event>" at the top left (just below the profile picture), where <event> is an upcoming event which is public, but which I haven't been invited to (so it doesn't show up in my events calendar).

Is there a way to see a list of such future events that this friend is going to, rather than just the one closest in time (which appears to be the one that shows up on their page)?

The closest thing I've found thus far is go to "Events Popular In Your Network" and scan that list for the friend's name, but that list is unlikely to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the search bar and query

> Friend Name's future events

or

`https://www.facebook.com/search/YOUR_FRIEND_ID_HERE/events/in-future/date/events/intersect`

For events the friend actually "joined"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/YOUR_FRIEND_ID_HERE/events-joined/in-future/date/events/intersect`